# Convert 2D array to multiple blocks of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a 16 x 4000 dimensional array to 1000 8 x 8 array blocks.I should end up with 1000 such blocks after I run this code. This is what I wrote and I need to know where I did wrong as this code gives me only 500 something blocks.

```
blockedCode(d);  //d is a two D 16 x 4000 array


 private static void blockedCode(int[][] array)
    {

        int one=0;


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 8)
        {           
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j += 8)
            {

                int block = (((i / 8) * 8) + (j / 8));


                System.out.println("Block : " + block);
                int[][] newArray = new int[8][8];
                int newRow = 0;
                List list = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int k = i; k < (i + 8); k++)
                {
                    int newColumn = 0;
                    for (int l = j; l < (j + 8); l++)
                    {
                        // This is where you are getting your array inside the given block.
                        newArray[newRow][newColumn] = array[k][l];
                        one++;

                      // System.out.format("[%-1s][%-1s] : %-3s ", newRow, newColumn, newArray[newRow][newColumn++]);
                    }

                    newRow++;
                }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method looks full of untested code, comments and empty lines... I advise you that you write your program from scratch using TDD, then you will know that it works.

Comment: I like `int one=0` :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your logic for calculating the block number:

```
int block = (((i / 8) * 8) + (j / 8));
```

It should be changed to :

```
int block = (((i/8) * (array[i].length/8)) + (j / 8));
```

Also you have to increment the newColumn variable inside the inner for loop..

```
for (int k = i; k < (i + 8); k++)
{
     int newColumn = 0;
     for (int l = j; l < (j + 8); l++)
     {
          // This is where you are getting your array inside the given block.
          newArray[newRow][newColumn] = array[k][l];
          one++;
          newColumn++;      //add this line

          // System.out.format("[%-1s][%-1s] : %-3s ", newRow, newColumn, newArray[newRow][newColumn++]);
     }
     newRow++;
}
```